# Problems connecting Docarray library to Langchain framework

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pydantic, langchain, docarray

I'm trying to run locally (Jupyter notebook) a piece of code from this DeepLearning.ai short course:
https://learn.deeplearning.ai/langchain/lesson/5/question-and-answer.

I copied their's code (which works on their's machine) but i'm getting this kinds of errors:

```
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.document_loaders import CSVLoader
from langchain.vectorstores import DocArrayInMemorySearch
from IPython.display import display, Markdown
from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.indexes import VectorstoreIndexCreator
```

For this piece of code:

```
file = 'OutdoorClothingCatalog_1000.csv'
loader = CSVLoader(file_path=file, encoding='utf-8')
index = VectorstoreIndexCreator(
vectorstore_cls=DocArrayInMemorySearch,
embedding=OpenAIEmbeddings()
).from_loaders(\[loader\])
```

I'm getting this error
...

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\docarray\array\any_array.py:54,
in AnyDocArray.**class_getitem**(cls, item)
51 @classmethod
52 def **class_getitem**(cls, item: Union[Type[BaseDocWithoutId], TypeVar, str]):
53     if not isinstance(item, type):
---> 54         return Generic.**class_getitem**.**func**(cls, item)  # type: ignore
55         # this do nothing that checking that item is valid type var or str
56     if not safe_issubclass(item, BaseDocWithoutId):
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '**func**'

And for this piece of code:

```
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
db = DocArrayInMemorySearch(
docs,
embeddings
)
query = "Please suggest a shirt with sunblocking"
docs = db.similarity_search(query)
```

I'm getting this error
...

```
File \~\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\langchain\\vectorstores\\docarray\\base.py:62,
in DocArrayIndex.doc_cls(self)
60 @property
61 def doc_cls(self) -\> Type\["BaseDoc"\]:
\---\> 62     if self.doc_index.\_schema is None:
63         raise ValueError("doc_index expected to have non-null \_schema attribute.")
64     return self.doc_index.\_schema
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '\_schema'
```

I suppose there are some problems with libraries (either this one or some other).
I tried installing previous versions of Docarray library but it didn't work.
I tried installing previous versions of Pydantic library but it didn't work either.
Those are just last few lines of error message (which is more than 100 lines).
Has anybody faced the same or similar issue or has knowledge on how to solve this problem?
Any help would be much appreciated.
Versions:
Python: 3.12.0
Langchain: 0.0.335
Docarray: 0.39.1
Pydantic: 1.10.13